# Mailchimp for dummies (php)

Tags: php, api, sendmail, mailchimp

I have a home made php script that can send an email.
Very simple :

```
$html = "<b>hello</b>";
$to = "johndoe@gmail.com";
$from = "me@server.com";

sendMAIL($from, $to, $html);
```

How can I replace those lines to use Mailchimp engine?
I have a Mailchimp account, and a Mailchimp API key.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

MailChimp itself does not support sending single/transactoinal emails.  If you want to have the ability to send a single/transactional email you will need to integrate MailChimp to Amazon Web Services Simple Email Service (SES) via the MailChimp STS API

MailChimp is geared towards sending emails/newsletters (campaigns) to multiple subscribers..

If you just need to send a single email, stick with your php solution...  (Or integrate to AWS SES via MC STS)